# How do you set fields on Household Accounts when upserting contacts?

Tags: apex, npsp

This customer has household accounts setup for npsp. When upserting a contact, is there a way to set fields on the household account?  Or, is the best practice to upsert the contact, then query for the account, and do a DML on the account?

```
  Contact con = new Contact();
  con.LastName = 'testLN';
  con.email = 'test@test.com';
  con.Account.Website = 'www.google.com' //results in an error
  con.externalId__c = '123';

  upsert con externalId__c ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Apex. Consider using the [Account & Contacts Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&type=5) to handle tasks like this, as it can update both in a single pass. In Apex, you need two DML statements, one for the contacts, one for the accounts.